# Fourier on chosen dimensions

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a data set `DATA` in 4 dimensions $A \times B \times C \times D$
and I want to use the `Fourier` function net only on the 2 and the 4 dimensions, $B$ and $D$.
When i'm applying `Fourier[DATA]`, it applies fft on all dimensions, which I don't want.
How can I use the `Fourier` function to do fft only on my chosen dimensions?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to apply a 2D Fourier transformation to the 2D slice corresponding to a[[1]] and d[[1]], then apply another 2D transform to the 2D slice with a[[1]] and d[[2]], etc?

Comment: No, i want to do 1D FFT in the B dimension and oin the D dimension

Comment: What are the dimensions of A, B, C, and D?

Comment: A=2,B=8,C=32,D=1024

Comment: Hi david - I'm confused. Take the D dimension with 1024 points. If your data is 4-dimensional, then for each of the other dimensions, there is a different set of 1024 points: when considering a[[1]], b[[1]], c[[1]] there is one set of Ds, when a[[2]], b[[1]], c[[1], there is another set of Ds etc. So are you trying to take 2*8*32 different 1D FFTs of the D-data?